# Writing file or copying file to a location in .net Core over http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In a ASP.Net Core 2.1 App I am writing byte array as a pdf file to a location with below code

```
byte[] arr = await rpt.BuildFile(actionContextAccessor.ActionContext);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "Storage", "PDF", HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserID"), Name), arr);
```

Now I also want to store same byte array as pdf over a http location

```
  string _path = "http://MyApps.in/document_1/" + Model.Identifier.Substring(0, 4) + "/" + Name;
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_path, arr);
```

But it does not seems to work this way look like `File.WriteAllBytes` does not write over HTTP location.

How can I write pdf file over HTTP location ??

Comment: You would need to use a http client and POST to the desired location provided a handler exists at that endponit

Comment: do you mean you want to write a byte array over HTTP... so the PDF can be downloaded?

Comment: No , don't want to download it , just want to store it there as backup

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518817/send-byte-array-by-http-post-in-store-app for an example how to post a byte array. if you need method=put HttpClient.PutAsync exists.