# It is possible to send get/post requests with string and byte array parameters?

Tags: c#, post, get, post-parameter

I have to send POST request to web service with multiple parameters where one of them has byte[] type. But I dont know how to pass byte[] parameter. Does anybody know? Also, I would like to know how to send byte[] array in GET requests. Any help will be appreciated!

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["thing1"] = "hello";
            values["thing2"] = "world"; // how to pass byte[] here?

            var response = client.UploadValues("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", values);

            var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
     }
```

or another variant with HttpClient:

```
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "thing1", "hello" },
       { "thing2", "world" } // how to pass byte[] here?
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Well, you can't pass a byte[] array if the structure you're using is string valued... unless you Base 64 encode it.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547930/3098521 and see if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Heretic Monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey) said in comments: Well, you can't pass a byte[] array if the structure you're using is string valued... unless you Base 64

Maybe in some cases you are right but:

**Convert.ToBase64String**
You can easily convert the output string back to byte array by using Convert.FromBase64String.
Note: The output string could contain '+', '/' and '='. If you want to use the string in a URL, you need to explicitly encode it. [© combo_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085028/6121574)

So, sometimes it is better to use **HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(byte[])** and decode it on server side.

But my problem was that web service could not accept large files. And the exception on client side that I got was "415: Unsupported Media Type". It was solved by changing config on the web service side:

```
<!-- To be added under <system.web> -->
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />

<!-- To be added under <system.webServer> -->
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

- Change the content-type of your request to a binary format. This would preclude including any strings.
- Use a [multi-part format like RFC 1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)
- Encode your binary data so it can be sent as a string. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is common.