# How to call web api with post request for sending file as byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, post, webapi

I'm trying to call a web api that takes byte array as parameter

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getfields")]
public List<string> GetFields(byte[] bytearray)
    {
        HelperClass pdf = new HelperClass ();
        List<string> fields = pdf.GetFormFields(bytearray);
        return fields;
    }
```

And i call the api as below:

```
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(TemplatePath);// pdf path
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("api/Controller/getfields", byteContent);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

I get error 500 and it doesn't go in the api controller. I have tried application/bson also that gives 415 error Unsupported Media Type. Thanks

Comment: Try using the full requestUri? eg "http://localhost:6969/api/Controller/getfields"

Comment: yes i m using full BaseAddress at my side.@mouldycurryness

Comment: Maybe give this solution a try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518817/send-byte-array-by-http-post-in-store-app

Comment: Already using the same : ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
HttpResponseMessage reponse = await client.PostAsync(uri, byteContent); 
@mouldycurryness